# error: source file is not valid UTF-8

Tags: c++, macos, vim, utf-8

I just found a problem when I try to build a c++ file in Mac OS 10.10.
I use vim to edit a very simple file: main.cpp . I just print "hello world" in that file.
But when I compile, I got this error:"

```
main.cpp:1:1: error: source file is not valid UTF-8
<CF><FA><ED><FE><U+0007>
^
main.cpp:1:2: error: source file is not valid UTF-8
<CF><FA><ED><FE><U+0007>
    ^
main.cpp:1:3: error: source file is not valid UTF-8
<CF><FA><ED><FE><U+0007>
        ^
main.cpp:1:4: error: source file is not valid UTF-8
<CF><FA><ED><FE><U+0007>
            ^
main.cpp:1:5: error: expected unqualified-id
<CF><FA><ED><FE><U+0007>
                ^
main.cpp:1:6: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
<CF><FA><ED><FE><U+0007>
                        ^
main.cpp:1:7: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
........."
```

3000 lines error and warning.

I did the same thing in ubuntu 12.04, everthing is fine, no error at all.

Anyone knows how to fix it, and what is the reason?

Thank you!

Comment: Or you may of course have used something other than a text editor (such as MS Word or LibreOffice Writer) to produce your source file - that would also cause this sort of problem. Clearly, your source file is not even close to a text-file.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Good guess, for a screwed makefile.

Comment: @AntonSavin This is not the BOM. The compiler on OS X recognizes the BOM, and if it had to print out source code that included that [it would print `<U+FEFF>`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/757eb1d2cbc8ac3b). Also in UTF-8 the BOM uses the bytes `<EF> <BB> <BF>`.

Comment: @bames53 I added that comment before the question was edited to show the compiler output correctly

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, vim is a very decent editor. It's not because you don't like it that it does not work right when used properly.

Comment: See this aswer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756343/clang-link-failure-error-source-file-is-not-valid-utf-8