# Installing Trilinos 13.0.1 with CUDA support and Clang 11.0.1-2 fails when linking Kokkoscore on Debian 11

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, clang, trilinos

I'm trying to install Trilinos 13.0.1 with `CUDA` support on my machine, using `clang`. For this I'm using `CMake` 3.18.4 and `make`. Here, the compilation terminates already during the linking of Kokkos-core with following error statements (they appear more often, I'll keep it short for now)

```
< Lots of output for building object files >

[ 2%] Linking CXX shared library libkokkoscore.so
clang: warning: Unknown CUDA version. No version found in version.txt or cuda.h. Assuming the latest supported version 10.1 [-Wunknown-cuda-version]
CMakeFiles/kokkoscore.dir/impl/Kokkos_CPUDiscovery.cpp.o:1:1: error: expected unqualified-id
<U+007F>ELF<U+0002><U+0001><U+0001><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0001><U+0000>><U+0000><U+0001><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><B0><U+0006><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>@<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>@<U+0000><U+000B><U+0000><U+0001><U+0000>S<BF>T<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><E8><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>H<89>ÿS<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><E8><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><85><C0><B9><FF><FF><FF><FF><89><D8><U+000F>N<C1><85><DB><U+000F>N<C1>[<C3><U+000F><U+001F>D<U+0000><U+0000>SH<8D>=<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><E8><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>H<85><C0>tGH<89><C7>1<F6><BA>
                         
CMakeFiles/kokkoscore.dir/impl/Kokkos_CPUDiscovery.cpp.o:1:8: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
<U+007F>ELF<U+0002><U+0001><U+0001><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0001><U+0000>><U+0000><U+0001><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><B0><U+0006><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>@<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>@<U+0000><U+000B><U+0000><U+0001><U+0000>S<BF>T<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><E8><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>H<89>ÿS<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><E8><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><85><C0><B9><FF><FF><FF><FF><89><D8><U+000F>N<C1><85><DB><U+000F>N<C1>[<C3><U+000F><U+001F>D<U+0000><U+0000>SH<8D>=<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><E8><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>H<85><C0>tGH<89><C7>1<F6><BA>

CMakeFiles/kokkoscore.dir/impl/Kokkos_CPUDiscovery.cpp.o:1:41: error: source file is not valid UTF-8
<U+007F>ELF<U+0002><U+0001><U+0001><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0001><U+0000>><U+0000><U+0001><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><B0><U+0006><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>@<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>@<U+0000><U+000B><U+0000><U+0001><U+0000>S<BF>T<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><E8><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>H<89>ÿS<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><E8><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><85><C0><B9><FF><FF><FF><FF><89><D8><U+000F>N<C1><85><DB><U+000F>N<C1>[<C3><U+000F><U+001F>D<U+0000><U+0000>SH<8D>=<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><E8><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>H<85><C0>tGH<89><C7>1<F6><BA>

< Repeating similar output for different lines of the same file >
```

The minimum example of my `configure` looks like this, the `INSTALL_DIR` is provided beforehand:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. \
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang \
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++ \
-DTrilinos_ENABLE_EXPLICIT_INSTANTIATION:BOOL=ON \
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-DTrilinos_ENABLE_CXX11=ON \
-DTPL_ENABLE_MPI=ON \
-DTPL_ENABLE_gtest=OFF \
-DTPL_ENABLE_CUDA=ON \
-DTrilinos_ENABLE_Gtest=OFF \
-DTrilinos_ENABLE_Tpetra=ON \
-DTrilinos_ENABLE_Xpetra=ON \
-DTrilinos_ENABLE_OpenMP=ON \
-DTrilinos_ENABLE_Belos=ON \
-DTrilinos_ENABLE_Kokkos=ON \
-DKokkos_ARCH_AMDAVX=ON \
-DKokkos_ARCH_PASCAL60=ON \
-DKokkos_ENABLE_CUDA_UVM=ON \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="${INSTALL_DIR}"
```

Subsequently, `make install` is called.

Here some additional details about my system:

- AMD Ryzen Threadripper 2950X
- Nvidia Quadro P1000
- Debian 11 (Bullseye)
- clang 11.0.1-2

The compilation using the same `configure` script, just with `-DTPL_ENABLE_CUDA=OFF` finishes without problems. So it seems to me that I have some problem related to either the architecture specification for my GPU, or I'm missing something when using `clang`.

Did anyone encounter a similar problem or has an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think this is related to one of the errors but don't think it will help fix the issue: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756343/clang-link-failure-error-source-file-is-not-valid-utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756343/clang-link-failure-error-source-file-is-not-valid-utf-8)

Comment: Whatever has broken, you are clearly passing binary elf files to the compiler to compile, which is wrong.

Comment: I also came to that conclusion, but now I'm interested, what causes this behavior? Ideally CMake should already create the MakeFile, which takes care of that for me.